# linq query for varchar field not returning any results

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, linqpad

When I run this query in **linqpad**:

```
Customer.Where(c => (c.CustomerName == "test"))
```

It returns a record that matches.

When I try running the same query in **visual studio** it does not return any matching records. This is the code I am using:

```
    List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();

    using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            customerList = db.Customer.Where(c => (c.customerName == "test")).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    return customerList;
```

Can anyone see why this it works in **linqpad** but does not work in **visual studio**?

Comment: If you debug, does the `db.Customer` object have a bunch of objects in them with at least one with "test" as the `customerName`? It looks straight forward enough for that to be the easiest issue.

Comment: You have different case of ``customerName`` in your VS code.  I don't know if that is just a typo here.  Also, the ``new List<Customer>()`` assignment is redundant because it will get overwritten by the query.

Comment: linqpad capitalises the object name, whereas VS does not change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try out like this

```
customerList = db.Customer.
   Where(c => String.Compare (c.customerName.ToUpper(),"test".ToUpper()) == 0).ToList();
```

because there may be problem with the Casesensitive search for customer name.

Try other variation of : [String.Compare Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2se42k1z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as per you need

Answer (score 0):

your linqpad query uses "c.CustomerName" and your visual studio query uses "c.customerName".

Alternatively your problem could be that it is case sensitive, or the db.Customer set is empty.

EDIT:
DeeMac has also covered this in his reply